# Python QuestDB - embed a function call in a query - HTTP REST API

Tags: python, questdb

Using SQL query within the console:

`select * from trades_one where traded_ts > dateadd('d', -1, now());`

OK

Using `HTTP REST API`

```
q = "select traded_price,"\
    " limit_price,"\
    " qty,"\
    " traded_ts,"\
    " timestamp"\
    " from trades_one"\
    " where traded_price < 1.6"

query = urllib.parse.quote(q)
r = requests.get("http://localhost:9000/exp?query=" + query)
queryData = r.content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(queryData.decode('utf-8')), parse_dates=['timestamp'])
print(rawData)
```

OK

now I wish to call this date-time function within the query:

```
dateadd('d', -1, now()
```

for result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [{"query":"select traded_price,  limit_price,  qty,  traded_ts,  timestamp from trades_one where traded_ts > dateadd('d',  -1,  now()", error:"unbalanced (", position:101}]
Index: []
```

Current syntax:

```
q = "select traded_price,"\
    " limit_price,"\
    " qty,"\
    " traded_ts,"\
    " timestamp"\
    " from trades_one"\
    " where traded_ts > dateadd('d', -1, now()"
```

How do I embed this date-time function `dateadd('d', -1, now()` into the `HTTP REST API` python query?

Documentation for the function:

https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/date-time

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i forgot a )

```
    " limit_price,"\
    " qty,"\
    " traded_ts,"\
    " timestamp"\
    " from trades_one"\
    " where traded_ts > dateadd('d', -1, now())"
```

works now - will leave the post up because someone else might find it useful on how to construct a query.